# Getting the current language in Aimeos

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Aimeos E-Commerce plugin on a Laravel site. I want to check the current language to switch the HTML rendering from Left To Right to Right To Left. I've checked it using

```
 dir="{{ Lang::locale() === "en" ? "ltr" : "rtl" }}"
```

but it always displays ltr. How to achieve that?

Comment: What does `Lang::locale()` return?

Comment: It always returns "en" even if I change the site language

Answer (score 0):

According to [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/localization#configuring-the-locale), You may use the `getLocale` and `isLocale` methods on the `App` facade to determine the current locale or check if the locale is a given value:

```php
dir="{{ App::isLocale('en') ? 'ltr' : 'rtl' }}"
```

Please note that you may change the active language at runtime using the `setLocale` method on the `App` facade:

```php
App::setLocale($locale);
```

Comment: thanks, I checked it but it gives me the same result. I'm using aimeos and it is responsible for setting the language, so I don't have to set the language myself